# python - take exact string based on regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have sample data in the following template

```
'Q31 P2852 Q25648793',
'Q31 P2852 Q25648794',
'Q31 P3916 concept893',
'Q31 P2633 Q1115035',
'Q31 P298 BEL',
'Q31 P1448 Belgick\u00E',
'Q31 P1448 K\u00F6nigreic',
```

The result should be like this

```
'Q31 P2852 Q25648793',
'Q31 P2852 Q25648794',
'Q31 P2633 Q1115035'
```

So, I just need take the data in the this format

```
format = Q[number] P[number] Q[number]
```

or in regex

```
pattern = r'Q[0-9]*\sP[0-9]*\sQ[0-9]*'
```

I already tried with a string it works but when I applied in txt file it didn't work.

```
data ='./sample/tes'

with open(data) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith('Q'):

            if re.match(r'Q[0-9]*\sP[0-9]*\sQ[0-9]*', line):
                print(line)

            else:
                print('not ok')

        else:
            pass
```

EDITED
I was trying to use `re.compile`, `re.findall`, `re.fullmatch` but it only read the first line. Idk why. Moreover, it don't really understand which `re` that I should use.

I am still learning regular expressions and I am not able to solve the above. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Btw, the real file is 1.5 TB.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `re.match(r"Q[0-9]*\sP[0-9]*\sQ[0-9]*"`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i tried, i didn't work

Comment: `p = "^Q[0-9]+\s*P[0-9]+\s*Q[0-9]+\s*$"` . I changed the `*` to a `+` after the `[0-9]` to mean "at least one, or any number of digits." The real issue (I think) was the `\s` to `\s*`. The former only checks for ONE space. The latter checks for "none, or any number of spaces."

Comment: [(?<!.)Q\[0-9\]* P\[0-9\]* Q\[0-9\]*(?!.)](https://regex101.com/r/4ilZNn/1) works for that Just read the whole file into a variable, then use _findall_

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also do a:

```
for line in infile.readlines():
```

as well as the suggestion given in the comment by @RomanPerekhrest

```
re.match(r"Q[0-9]*\sP[0-9]*\sQ[0-9]*"
```